# Deploying React and Nodejs to the same Heroku Dyno

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy both a React app and a Nodejs backend to the same Heroku app following [this](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node) guide. Everything seemed to work fine and the app built successfully, however it's only serving the backend (api) part of the project and not the front end.

This is my package.json that's located outside both the client and server folders.

```
{
  "name": "web-back",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd react-ui && npm start",
    "dev-server": "cd server && nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run dev-server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node server",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd react-ui/ && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "react-ui/node_modules"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.11"
  }
}
```

This is server/index.js

```
const express       = require('express'),
      mongo         = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mongoURL = process.env.DBURL || "mongodb://localhost/test"; 

mongo.connect(mongoURL); 

const CommandSchema = mongo.Schema({
    Command: String, 
    Text: String
}, { collection: "Commands" });

const Command = mongo.model("Command", CommandSchema); 

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    Command.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        else res.send(result); 
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

This is my folder structure.

[image]

Did I miss something when setting up?

Comment: What does your `server/index.js` look like?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Edited to show server/index.js

Comment: Ah thanks, but that's not what I was looking for actually. Where do you issue the commands to the build server to run both of the apps?

Comment: I see what you're talking about. I didn't have one. Just tried using `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname), '../react-ui/build'));` like the one in the example but I get the following error now: `TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: ../react-ui/build
    at Function.create (<anonymous>)`.

This is only when testing locally, haven't tried on Heroku.

Comment: Was using path.resolve wrong, this is the correct usage `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react-ui/build')));`.